# How do I distribute a value over multiple cells evenly but under a maximum limit?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Example data with desired outcome that I need to calculate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLIpp.png)

I have 12 items of a certain current value. I have a 'soft' cap of $1,000,000 for these values. Some of the items fall above, and some below this cap level.

I have an amount of money (for this example $900,000) that I want to distribute amongst only the items that fall below the cap (in this example 6 items), with the aim of bringing the value of these items up to but not over the cap value.

If I distribute the $900,000 evenly over these 6 items (each receiving $150,000), you can see that items 2 and 9 would then be over the $1,000,000 cap. So items 2 and 9 should only receive $100,000 to raise their value to the cap, then the remaining 4 items would receive and equal share on the remaining pool of money ($700,000 / 4 = $175,000).

So I need a formula to check every item to see if it needs a distribution (i.e below the cap) and then portion/divide out the money pool as illustrated above in the desired distribution column.

Note: The pool of money to be distributed can change. Also the number of items below the cap can change. The cap value itself can change.
I am hoping to avoid VBA or Solver because the spreadsheet could be used on other people's computers.

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

So far I have been able to get close by adding a helper column and using the following formula:

=IF(SUM($F$6:F14)=$D$23,0,E15*MIN(D15,($D$23-SUM($F$6:F14))/SUM(E15:$E$18)))

[Working example when values are sorted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE05A.png)

This seems to work when the values are sorted in descending order, as shown in the example image above. But seems to break when the values are a bit more randomly assorted which is likely to happen (as in the original post).

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? This looks quite fun to solve but I can't see what effort you have put in.

Comment: Ooh this does seem interesting, but as stated, it's important to share your attempt: the code you have so far, the desired end-result, and explanation of where you're stuck.  See "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]**.  Also [here is a checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.  You can [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: From just reading without looking at your links, you could look at the use of the solver and setting constraints about the min and max limits of the values.

Comment: Maybe you could use the Max Min Fair algorithm? https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/writing-efficient-udfs-part13-maxminfair-allocation-an-array-udf-example/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and advice. I've edited my question to provide more info on what I've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea of how the solver can be set up to do a capital budget model here is one, also shows the solver and its settings:

[image]